# android orientation doesn't work

Tags: android, orientation

I'm making an android app. My screen is not changing the orientation of the activity. The android version is 2.3.6 on a samsung pocket.

Following the layout screen.

edit: sorry this tag head below was missing because it was the right below line, how you can see the xml missing part.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/Custom2ActionBarTheme"
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know what else to do, I looked for the solution through google but I couldn't find the answer.

Help

Comment: Can other apps on the phone rotate? Perhaps you have auto-rotation disabled in the phone's settings.

Comment: there is a detail.. the android:orientation is working on the emulator which is executing an emulation to the android 4.0. Maybe is some problem of compatibility, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phone: http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphone/GT-S5300ZKATGY-features

Does it definitely have a sensor to know its been changed in orientation? In your settings is auto-rotate switched off?

I can't see any issue in what you've posted that I know would stop orientation changes working.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the answer. My cellphone has a sensor to change orientation. I know that because I have other aplications which I got from google play that do this funcionality. My folder layout is inside the folder res. The phone picture you mentioned is the one I have.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That was a little idiot problem... My settings to auto-rotate was switched off... Maybe the other applications which are working that rotation on my cellphone is because they are doing that programmatically in case the user turns it off like I did!

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers mentions - first you need to check if phone has the ability and then check to see that you do not have the setting disabled in Android.

In your app, "layout" folder under "red" - do you have a "layout-land" folder in which you are defining a layout file that specifies the landscape layout.

Create a layout-land directory (under "res" folder) and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

Comment: This answer proposes a good way to check for issues, but (im not sure if you are aware user1406716), the landscape isn't required, it's just a way to optimize

Comment: Hi. I don't have folder layout-land under res, just the folder layout which contains the that xml above.

Comment: I believe you are correct Nick Cardoso because I didn't see some mention about to be necessary doing that to the orientation works.